# 4G module returns CME ERROR:15 when I opend my own applet in the SIM card with AT+CCHO command

Tags: smartcard, at-command, javacard, sim-card, lte

everyone, I'm developing a project with LTE 4G module and having a problem described as following:

1. I write a SIM card application (with Java tech) and download it into the SIM Card.
2. After downloading the applet, inert the SIM card into a card reader, then I can send APDUs to the applet through this card reader. applet works fine ,it accepts the APDU and gives the response back.
3. After finishing the APDU test , I insert the SIM card to the LTE 4G module ,and send **AT+CCHO="A0BB01020304050001"**(A0BB01020304050001 is my applet DF name) through uart to open the applet, the 4G module returns **+CME ERROR: 15**(SIM Wrong).But some other original applet(such as USIM) in the card can be opend normally in this way.

so,does anyone know whether there are some key points I have to pay attention to my applet or the AT+CCHO command? I'll be very appreciated and willing to give what all I have.

Comment: Does you applet and card support logical channels (e.g. applet extends MultiSelectable)?

Comment: yes, the module supports CCHO and card does too. but applet MultiSelectable, I'm not quite sure. I only need to build one channel to the applet, so does it matter ? or how can i know whether it's MultiSelectable or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,finally it proved that no matter what you sent to the App through CGLA, the App must gave back something to the 4G module, otherwise the module released +CME ERROR: 15.